# Search for file names in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I have about 50K files in an s3 bucket and I need to search in those files on a recurrent basis (maybe 5-10 times a day). These 50K is fixed set of files, but there could be new files.

Search in these 50K+ files 10 times a day would be expensive. I was thinking to create a flat text file and keep the names of these 50K files in that text file. I will then download this files locally and search in this file.

The problem with this approach is - how will I keep updating the text file with the name of new files?

I don't need the file contents. I only need to check if file exist or not.

My programming language is Java.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Setup a [S3 Inventory Report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html) and use the file it produces.

Comment: Thanks! But with Inventory - there is no way for me to know when there are new files, correct? I can't rebuild the inventory report when there are new files. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Correct, S3 Inventory updates every 24 hours, if you want an up-to-the-moment list of files, you'll need to create a list yourself, and maintain it with, for instance with a Lambda triggered off object notifications.

Comment: Maybe you can set up an S3 event for new files and send it to an SQS? With that, you just need to read this SQS to get the name of the new files, and you can empty this SQS after that.